# Using arrays to store multiple IDs or classes, and then manipulating them in functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I have a set of classes stored in a JavaScript array called 'targets' as follows:

#### HTML

```
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
<div id="four">4</div>
<div id="five">5</div>
<div id="six">6</div>
<div id="seven">7</div>
<div id="eight">8</div>
<div id="nine">9</div>
<div id="ten">10</div>
```

#### JavaScript — Array

```
var targets = ["#one", "#two", "#three", "#four", "#five", "#six", "#seven", "#eight", "#nine", "#ten"];
```

I would then like to manipulate them to use in functions. Depending on my situation, I'd either want to target one specific ID from the array, or all entries in the array at once. I do understand that each entry into an array is given a unique index number, starting with 0. Therefore, `#one` is index 0, and `#ten` is index 9.

I also understand that I can use `for` loops with arrays, that will cycle through each entry. My issue is that I can't seem to get my function working when it is called from a click event (on an `input type="button"` element).

Here are two examples of my code. One targets one specific entry, the other targets them all. Or at least, that is what it should be doing. Chrome's console shows no errors with my code, and I have never really worked with arrays, so this is a first for me.

#### JavaScript — Attempting to Target a Single Entry (Working)

```
$(targets[0]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
```

#### JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries I

```
$(targets).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

#### JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries II

```
targets.forEach(function() {
    $(targets).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

#### JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries III

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i ) {
    $(targets).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
}
```

Also, I know that jQuery allows you to manipulate multiple classes and/or IDs at once by passing multiple values through the `$()` part of the code, but I'm in a predicament where the entries of the array will be different, depending on user input, and I feel that I will be manipulating in excess of 250 different IDs and classes in total. I've simply omitted the HTML code to the first 10 elements.

The majority of the 250 IDs/classes, are located on `<option>` elements. The `.show` and `.hide` classes used in the code are not applied directly to the `<option>` elements themselves, but to `<select>` elements that contain these options. Each `<select>` element has a unique ID.

If I can just figure out how to do this with arrays, everything will be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: far too much use of `each` . Can perform most jQuery methods on the whole collection. `$(selector)` creates an array of the elements within the jQuery object

Comment: overall I would say your approach is more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting on your approaches in order:

**JavaScript — Attempting to Target a Single Entry (Working)**

This one is working (as you say). You can use similar techniques to get at ALL elements in the array of id-s:

```
$(targets[0]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
$(targets.join(",")).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
```

However the *common* way is to add a `class` attribute rather than an `id`. After all - remember - that's what classes are for. Any DOM element can (and usually does) have a multitude of classes.

```
<div id="one" class="number">1</div>
<div id="two" class="number">2</div>
<!-- ... and so on -->
```

The above two lines become equivalent to:

```
// These two lines are each equivalent to $(target[0])
$(".number").eq(0).addClass('hide').removeClass('show'); // or even...
$(".number")[0].addClass('hide').removeClass('show');

// This is equivalent to $(target.join(","))
$(".number").addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
```

**JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries I**

The [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function can only be called on jQuery objects. You can't use it on an array, but you can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead:

```
$.each(targets, function(idx, obj) {
    $(obj).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

**JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries II**

When using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you need to (ok, not *need to*, but at least *should*) make use of the parameters passed to your callback:

```
targets.forEach(function(elt, idx, arr) {
    $(elt).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    // ... OR ...
    $(arr[idx]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    // ... OR ...
    $(targets[idx]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

**JavaScript - Attempting to Target All Entries III**

`$(targets)` selects nothing. It doesn't throw an error (though it probably ought to). You access array elements with the `[index]` notation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i ) {
    $(targets[i]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Attempt III is what I am currently still using. Your simple fix of adding in the `i` did the trick. I was under the impression that `targets` would select everything, rather than nothing. I guess that was one pitfall of being a noob with arrays. Also, thank you to @AlexandruSeverin for providing the same answer. @blgt did however explain it in a clearer context for an array noob!

Comment: Np, the point in (III) was that a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) has to be in a `string` type; whereas in your case `targets` is of type `object` which is what all arrays are (an array of strings is still not a `string`) : )

Answer (score 4):

You have to join the array in to a string that is a valid jQuery selector

```
$(targets.join(', ')).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
```

This will give you

```
$("#one, #two, #three ...")
```

which is valid, an array of ID's is not a valid selector

Also note that showing and hiding option elements is not cross browser

Comment: In regards to show/hide, I am using separate `<select>` elements to categorize the options. The classes are supplied to these `<select>` elements, rather than the `<option>` elements themselves. I did previously try some show/hide trickery with `<option>` elements and found out that problems would occur. That is why I have now gone with the separate, categorized `<select>` method instead. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: With selects there's shouldn't be an issue, I just noticed that you wrote option elements, and that the classes had names like "hide" and "show", and thought I should mention that there are issues with that.

Comment: I have edited that last paragraph to try and explain the usage a little clearer. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop you're query-ing the whole list everytime and not specific elements, (add [i] to targets)

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i ) {
    $(targets[i]).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
}
```